# would there be much added latency for a web-app if it only used firestore indirectly via a node express REST api hosted on app engine?

Tags: firebase, google-app-engine, architecture, google-cloud-firestore

I have a progressive web app (pwa) which uses firebase authentication. The back-end app -- a node.js express app hosted on GAE -- needs to perform complex data transformations and multi-step async operations. The pwa could use firestore directly for about a third of the data-related functions, but for the more complex operations, it would need to talk to the express app.

For simplicity, I'd rather have the pwa just use the express app. Would there be much added latency than using firestore directly?

Answer (score 1):

There shouldn't be. Assuming your GAE app is in us-central1, then it will be served from the same data centers as your Cloud Firestore database. The extra hop to your GAE shouldn't add much since it's essentially local.

There might be some minor differences due to things that sit above GAE to handle routing/load-balancing, etc, but it will probably be milliseconds of difference.

The largest difference will likely be from processing time in your node.js app itself.